# Hashing runs out of memory, and getting slower and slower over time

Tags: java, memory, memory-management, hash, memory-leaks

I have a GUI desktop application which generates different types of hash (example MD5) for files and directories. Recently, when I was testing with a 1GB test file I recognized that it becomes slower and slower over time. At the first hashing, it takes about 2 seconds for a 1GB file, however later, for the exactly same file, it takes about 76 seconds.

To demonstrate the problem, I have created a sample code that everyone can try (for repeatability). It has 2 key steps (1) generates a byte array for the file, (2) generates the hash for the byte array. (In the real program there are several switches and if-else statements, for example to decide if it is a file or directory...etc., and lot of javaFX GUI elements involved...)

I'll show that even this simplified code becomes 8 times slower by repeating it 5 times! As I read multiple forums it is probably the reason of memory leaking or too much memory consumption...or something similar. What I want is, I'd like to empty the memory between each cycle, so hashing would take only the time as the first time (2 seconds).

The mentioned sample code is the following:

```
package main;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import org.springframework.util.StopWatch;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {

        // 1GB Test file downloaded from here:
        // https://testfiledownload.com/

        StopWatch sw = new StopWatch();
        // Hash the file 5 times and measure the time for each hashing
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            sw.start();
                String hash = encrypt(inputparser("C:\\Users\\Thend\\Downloads\\1GB.bin"));
            sw.stop();
            // Print execution time at each cycle
            System.out.println("Execution time: "+String.format("%.5f", sw.getTotalTimeMillis() / 1000.0f)+"sec"+" Hash: "+hash);
        }
    }

    public static byte[] inputparser(String path){
        File f = new File(path);
        byte[] bytes = new byte[(int) f.length()];
        FileInputStream fis = null;
        try {
            fis = new FileInputStream(f);
            // read file into bytes[]
            fis.read(bytes);
            if (fis != null) {
                fis.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return bytes;
    }

    public static String encrypt(byte[] bytes) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        md.reset();
        md.update(bytes);

        byte[] hashed_bytes = md.digest();

        // Convert bytes[] (in decimal format) to hexadecimal
        for (int i = 0; i < hashed_bytes.length; i++) {
            sb.append(Integer.toString((hashed_bytes[i] & 0xff) + 0x100, 16).substring(1));
        }

        // Return hashed String in hex format
        String hashedByteArray = sb.toString();
        return hashedByteArray;
    }
}
```

The console output, where you can see the increasing time:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-18.0.2\bin\java.exe" "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2022.2\lib\idea_rt.jar=54323:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2022.2\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dsun.stdout.encoding=UTF-8 -Dsun.stderr.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath C:\Users\Thend\intellij-workspace\HashTimeTest\out\production\HashTimeTest;C:\Users\Thend\Downloads\springframework-5.1.0.jar main.Main
Execution time: 2,04100sec Hash: e5c834fbdaa6bfd8eac5eb9404eefdd4
Execution time: 3,70900sec Hash: e5c834fbdaa6bfd8eac5eb9404eefdd4
Execution time: 5,42100sec Hash: e5c834fbdaa6bfd8eac5eb9404eefdd4
Execution time: 7,09600sec Hash: e5c834fbdaa6bfd8eac5eb9404eefdd4
Execution time: 8,75500sec Hash: e5c834fbdaa6bfd8eac5eb9404eefdd4

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Your code proves nothing since `sw.getTotalTimeMillis()` is cumulative: if there is one second between the first `sw.start()` and `sw.stop()` it returns 1000 milliseconds. If there is another second between the second `sw.start()` and `sw.stop()` it will return a total of 2000 ms. To take real measurements you should create the `StopWatch` within the for loop.

Comment: @ThomasKläger you are completely right, then now I know even less what the problem is with my code :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably your problem is that you store a reference to the loaded file somewhere.

A better approach to do an operation like a hash calculation over a big file is to **not** load everything into memory but to load it only piece by piece:

```
public static String encrypt(String path) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    File f = new File(path);
    byte[] bytes = new byte[4096];
    MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
    try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f)) {
        while (true) {
            int len = fis.read(bytes);
            if (len == -1) {
                break;
            }
            md.update(bytes, 0, len);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    byte[] hashed_bytes = md.digest();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < hashed_bytes.length; i++) {
        sb.append(String.format("%02x", hashed_bytes[i]));
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: Recently, I have tried the to hash the same file with **BCrypt** and it resulted in `Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space` so can this be the reason? If you limit byte array to 4096 bytes, will it read in the whole file? (I trying you code at the moment..)

Comment: Also, is this possible to separate the steps in you code, as formerly I did, first to generate the byte array, second to encrypt to get the hash? My program is based on this, and if its not possible I have to rewrite everything :(

Comment: 1) Yes.  2) Yes. 3) Not without a risk of an OOME because the file is too large to fit in the JVM's heap.

Comment: The `OutOfMemoryError` will happen if you try to read a file that is either greater than the available memory, or larger than 2’147’483’647 bytes (because you cannot create arrays with more than about 2’147’483’640 elements). My approach processes the whole file (it reads a buffer full until reaches the end of the file).

Comment: If you need to process files larger than 2 GB (2’147’483’647 bytes) you will have to change your approach anyway, so it is probably better to do it now.

Comment: @ThomasKläger If I load my files piece by piece, as you wrote in your code, can I process for example files with 10 GB? Is this way, does the processing time will be the same for each file?

Comment: @StephenC may I kindly ask give me a suggestion how to separate the steps? If it is possible, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: @Thend yes, by processing the files piece by piece you can process files of any size. For large files the processing time will mainly be determined by the speed of reading the data into memory.

Comment: *"give me a suggestion how to separate the steps?"* - Basically, you do what you are currently doing, which as you observed can result in OOMEs.  Therefore it is a bad idea.  (But you *already* know how to do it ... so don't need my suggestion.)

Comment: @ThomasKläger May I kindly ask, what is the appropriate or recommended byte[] size? The one you used (4096) is sufficient for processing large files or for example if I want to hash a hard disk? (I will process multiple files parallel with ExecutorServices)

Comment: @Thend the optimal size might depend on the computer you are running this on. If you have time you can do several test runs, doubling the value (4096, 8192, 16384, 32768, ...) until you a point where the running time starts to increase. On my machine the sweet spot seems to be with the values 32768, 65536 and 131072.